# Sql query build

Tags: sql

Could you pls help me on the below query,

I have queried a result set by joining two three tables as below,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGVH4.png)

My requirement is to get the subsequent two dates after 20170701 and before 20170701.

eg. 456 account having date entries like 20160625, 20160725, 20160825, 20160925 , 20170725, 20170825, 20170925..

but the result should be 2 entries < 20170701 > 2 entries

Screenshot attached for example, where green rows should come in the final result.

please help

Comment: Can you please add the code you wrote that is producing the incorrect result?

Comment: Please DO not post data or code as images but as text.

Comment: with cte as (
my select query with joins) 
select cte.* 
from ( select cte.*, rank() over (partition by ac_no, case when tran_date > 20170701 then 1 else 2 end order by ac_no, tran_date) as seqnum
from cte)
but its giving the number to all the data, eg. 
20170216 - 1
20170302 - 2
20170402 - 3.
20170706 - 1
20170720 - 2
but i need the last two entries only
and also need entries immediate before 20170701
so , if having below entries 
20170602
20170502
20170402
20170302

so i need here only 20170602 and 20170502 which is closest to the 20170701 but not exceeding 20170701

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sum` analytical function as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select t.*,
       Sum(case when date > 20200701 then 1 end) 
          over (partition by account order by date) as sm_i,
       Sum(case when date < 20200701 then 1 end) 
          over (partition by account order by date desc) as sm_d
  From your_table t) t
 Where sm_i between 1 and 2 or sm_d between 1 and 2
```

Comment: Awesome!!!! thanks so much @Popeye ... I am testing the query fully and will let you know... again thanks